# How to Amend Environmental Variables Using Command Line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I am attempting to set up a small deployment that requires editing of system variables. I have used SETX in the past to create new variables and set values of existing ones. However, SETX does not appear to allow adding an existing string to a previously defined value.
For example, lets say I had a system variable FRED with value "BLA" and I wanted to add "FOO" such that the new value was "BLAFOO." It appears SETX does not allow me to set it by calling the value, %FRED% and then adding whatever I want at the end. This is what I have done when using temporary variables with the SET command.
Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to show us what you have tried and state step-by-step how you tested.

```
setx fred %fred%foo
```

will work BUT `setx` only sets the environment for **FUTURE** cmd invocations, not existing.

```
set fred=%fred%foo
setx fred %fred%
```

will set `fred` for the current and future, but not other `cmd` instances already started.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
PATH
SETX PATH "c:\123;%path%;"
PATH
PAUSE
```

missing the double quotes maybe?